# Locking and protecting selected cells through an Office Script

Tags: excel, dynamic, power-automate, office-scripts

I am trying to write an Office Script code to work with a power automate flow. The code is going to unprotect a document, lock a range of cells that were unlocked (determined by the power automate flow) and then re-protect the document. So far I have figured out how to write the working code to protect the document, lock all cells (the variable doesn't pull through), and re-protect the document. How do I pull the variable range though to lock only selected rows from the power automate flow?

[image: Picture of code]

I have tried moving the variable to various places in the code and trying to identify range on its own it the variable but there have been so many tests I cant remember all the variations.
So far I have been able to unlock all the cells or lock all the cells not the specific range.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
      let ws = workbook.getActiveWorksheet()
      
      if (ws.getProtection().getProtected()) {
        ws.getProtection().unprotect("password")
      }
    
      ws.getRange().getFormat().getProtection().setLocked(false)
      workbook.getSelectedRange().getFormat().getProtection().setLocked(true)
      ws.getProtection().protect({selectionMode:ExcelScript.ProtectionSelectionMode.unlocked},"password")
    }
```

By default, cells in the worksheet will be set to locked. So if you lock the sheet they will be protected. So you have to start out by unlocking all of the cells in the sheet.

You can determine the selected range by using `Workbook.getSelectedRange()`. Selecting ranges in code is not typically recommended. So I'd see if there's some other way you can determine the range dynamically from PowerAutomate. But if you can't that's fine too.

From there, you have to pass in the `selectionMode` parameter in the options. And set the option to `ExcelScript.ProtectionSelectionMode.unlocked`